# Define stub/mock expectation/should_receive in one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2, rspec-rails

Anyone know of a way to shorten this to one line? (RSpec 2)

```
location = mock
location.should_receive(:build)
```

For example, you can define the following:

```
location = stub
location.stub(build: true)
```

The above is the same as:

```
location = stub(build :true)
```

So, anyone see a way to specify an expectation in the mock call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`location = mock.tap { |loc| loc.should_receive(:build) }`

Comment: LOVE this. kudos to you, good sir. Will leave open for a couple more hours if there are other solutions, but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks ugly, though works:

```
    (location = mock).should_receive(:build)
```

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought of that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If every your test has mock definition, you can shorten the notation by using **let** in the beginning of file.

```
let (:location) { double :location }
```

Then every time when you're using `location`, it automatically creates new mock object:

```
location.should_receive(:build)
```

Comment: Right on, used similar methods in the past and works well when you want to use same mock throughout a context.

Comment: As far as I know, it should creates new mock object for every scope. It could be handy.

Comment: `location` will be instantiated again for each example. This would probably be the best approach to use, especially if you need to set the expectation in some examples and not in others.